# Apache Tomcat is installed or not?

Tags: linux, tomcat

How can I check whether Apache Tomcat is installed or not in my remote linux machine. I am using putty for connecting the machine. Is there any command to find that?

Comment: What OS is the server running? Most package managers have a way of querying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned that you're running Ubuntu. Ubuntu is Debian based, so you would use `dpkg`

```
dpkg -l | grep tomcat
```

This will first list all installed packages, then search for something that contains tomcat. If tomcat shows up, then it's installed.

See [this blog post](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-debian-package-management-cheat-sheet.html) for more useful commands.